# How to solve this set of integral equations?

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations, constraints

Given some known functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, is it possible to find all solutions $\psi(x)$ that satisfy the following constraints?

$$1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,f(x)\psi(x)$$
$$1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,g(x)\psi(x)$$

If so, how exactly can this be done?

Comment: @clathratus Note that if we set, e.g. $\psi=\frac{\delta(x)}{f(x)}$, this would satisfy the first equation but not the second. A valid solution $\psi$ should satisfy both equations simultaneously, which is why I believe a Dirac delta function is not a solution of this problem. Please, do elaborate on this if you believe this conclusion is wrong.